# C# Generics abuse?

Tags: c#, generics

I can't figure out why I am getting the error `cannot be used as type parameter 't' in the generic type or method...There is no implicit reference conversion from...`

Here is my entire piece of code (simplified):

The problem is on the line `RefreshLocalListFromLocalStore(TestDataObjectTable);`

```
using System;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync;

public class TestDataObject
{
    #region Properties

    public string Id { get; set; }

    #endregion
}

public class TestDatabaseManager
{
    public MobileServiceClient Client;

    private IMobileServiceSyncTable<TestDataObject> TestDataObjectTable;

    public TestDatabaseManager()
    {
        CurrentPlatform.Init();
        Client = new MobileServiceClient("SomeUrl");
        var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore("SomePath");
        store.DefineTable<TestDataObject>();

        TestDataObjectTable = Client.GetSyncTable<TestDataObject>();

        RefreshLocalListFromLocalStore(TestDataObjectTable);
    }

    #region Methods

    public async void RefreshLocalListFromLocalStore<T>(T table) where T : IMobileServiceSyncTable<T>
    {
        try
        {
            await table.ToListAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Does TestDataObjectTable satisfy the type constraint, must implement IMobileServiceSyncTable<T>?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response Glen. No, it doesn't - the full code is above. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Either remove the constraint (but will then will need to specify type explicitly to call the ToListAsync method) or make TestDataObjectTable implement IMobileServiceSyncTable<T>

Answer (score 0):

Your generic constraint is probably wrong. Use the following declaration for `RefreshLocalListFromLocalStore`:

```
public async void RefreshLocalListFromLocalStore<T>(IMobileServiceSyncTavble<T> table)
```

In your declaration, the table should have been a table of tables, which does not make sense. You can use the generics constraints still to limit what kind of elements you want to have for your table, for example if the elements in the table should be entities complying with some `IEntity` interface.

```
public async void RefreshLocalListFromLocalStore<T>(IMobileServiceSyncTavble<T> table) where T : IEntity
```

Comment: Thanks for all the comments guys - will try these solutions out - much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
  T is IMobileServiceSyncTable<TestDataObject>

  T must implement IMobileServiceSyncTable<T>
```

but it doesn't, because that would be

```
  IMobileServiceSyncTable<IMobileServiceSyncTable<TestDataObject>>
```

Try this instead:

```
public async void RefreshLocalListFromLocalStore<T>(IMobileServiceSyncTable<T> table) 
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: You are a friggin genius!  This worked....thanks ever so much...now for a major refactor throughout my code...should take 1000 lines to about 30... ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're using T with constraint of Type `IMobileServiceSyncTable<T>` where T is again of Type `IMobileServiceSyncTable<T>`.

Use constraints on the type for generic interface

```
public async void RefreshLocalListFromLocalStore<T>(IMobileServiceSyncTable<T> table) 
                                                                  where T : TestDataObject
{

}
```

See [specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) of using Type constraints.